# "Save as" title for selecting location

Tags: gui-design, labels, save

i have an UI Element :

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmGbaY.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I cant figure out the title/label I need to give this UI element. The element is used for choosing a location for files that will be saved if Save button is clicked. Usually in software I use title "Save as" for saving files, but that is common as a title for selecting a location:

Where? Location? Path?

Comment: Just to clarify: is saving a separate action to selecting the save location?

Comment: I like "Location" but maybe an idea to extend it to "File Location:", "Folder Location:".

Comment: Dose it have to short for any reason? Could you not use "select location" or "choose location"?

Comment: dhmholley: Yes saving is a seperate action.

Also in the selected folder will also Created lots of Files and Folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably depends a bit on the other functionality of the form, and  your general persistence model.

Without additional information, I'd say *"Save As"* or *"Saved as"* wins simply because it's common.